# What does "be held to" mean in the phrase "a lighter is held to a candle"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

The following sentence is found in [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flame) Wikipedia page about *Flame*:

> Color and temperature of a flame are dependent on the type of fuel involved in the combustion, as, for example, when a lighter is held to a candle.

I don't know how to interpret the phrase "a lighter is held to a candle".

I know that a candle is often ignited by a lighter, so "a lighter is held to a candle" probably means that after igniting the candle, the lighter continues burning along with the illuminating ignited candle. So the light becomes brighter than when the lighter stops burning after ignition because there are two sources providing light now.

However, I'm not sure that interpretation is correct (in common sense) or not?

Answer (score 3):

Holding a lighter *to* something is just holding the (lit) lighter close enough to ignite it. This lasts as long as they're physically close and your intent is to light it, both before and after the candle actually catches fire.

More generally, holding X to Y is holding X in a specific position near Y for a specific purpose: hold a scanner to a barcode; hold a magnifying glass to a document; hold a jewel to the sun. This doesn't mean you can rely on it being idiomatic for any given scenario, so pay attention to how native speakers use it.

Comment: It's the very common interpretation I could think of when I first saw the sentence. But in this specific context, that interpretation doesn't help much, does it?

Comment: @TranKhanh - In this specific context, 'that interpretation' is exactly perfect and accurate, is it not?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey, Pls help me to understand it because I can't see why the color and temperature of the flame of a candle vary if a lighter is held to a candle (according to the interpretation provided in the answer)?

Comment: @TranKhanh It's awkwardly phrased IMO, but the next sentences of the article use a lighter and candle as an example, and this sentence is just introducing it.

Comment: @the-baby-is-you I found only a candle not a lighter in the whole page?